# Select multiple values from two tables using horizontal relation with other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

All experts

Pardon me for the subject I was not able to figure out any thing else that explains the scenario.

I am working with a old database that has lot of crappy database issues.

**Table Structure**

Table: Brand

id
Name
muId (LpMap table  LpID and same for rest of the four)
Mid
Wid
Bid
Gid

Table : LpMap
LpId
Name
Asscoiate Id (fk from LpMapConfig)

Table : LpMapConfig >
id
Lpid
 dateCreated

**Data** Posting images for tabular representation of data
[image]

[image]

Desired Output
[image]

So What i wanted to do is- write a sql query that fetches  Id, Name and count of (Mid,MEid, Gid ,Wid Bid) if all the five have value then count will be 5 any one of them is null then it will be 4.

Comment: whay do you need the other tables for? what you need can be achieved with the `brand` table alone?

Comment: @vkp you are correct. I wanted to perform one more thing so thought of posting it with them. Can you suggest how can we achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select name, id,
case when mid is not null then 1 else 0 +
case when meid is not null then 1 else 0 +
case when gid is not null then 1 else 0 +
case when wid is not null then 1 else 0 +
case when bid is not null then 1 else 0 
end as count
from BRAND
```